# html making div to image

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to convert div content in to image by this link https://codepedia.info/convert-html-to-image-in-jquery-div-or-table-to-jpg-png  now I'm abele to convert div to image but problem is it was not download directly it asking 1st take preview after it give download help me to without viewing preview directly download.

**code**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>
        <p style="color: #3e4b51;">
            <b>Codepedia.info</b> is a programming blog. Tutorials focused on Programming ASP.Net,
            C#, jQuery, AngularJs, Gridview, MVC, Ajax, Javascript, XML, MS SQL-Server, NodeJs,
            Web Design, Software</p>
        <p style="color: #3e4b51;">
            <b>html2canvas</b> script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts
            of it, directly on the users browser. The screenshot is based on the DOM and as
            such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation.
        </p>
    </div>
    <input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div id="previewImage">
    </div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    
var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable
 
    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
    });

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this code, download it and run it on the browser. the download will not work directly from StackOverflow

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong>
        <hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>
        <p style="color: #3e4b51;">
            <b>Codepedia.info</b> is a programming blog. Tutorials focused on Programming ASP.Net, C#, jQuery, AngularJs, Gridview, MVC, Ajax, Javascript, XML, MS SQL-Server, NodeJs, Web Design, Software</p>
        <p style="color: #3e4b51;">
            <b>html2canvas</b> script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it, directly on the users browser. The screenshot is based on the DOM and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation.
        </p>
    </div>
    <input download="download.png" id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Download" />
    <br/>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {


            var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
            var getCanvas; // global variable
            var newData;

            $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function() {
                html2canvas(element, {
                    onrendered: function(canvas) {
                        getCanvas = canvas;
                        var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                        var a = document.createElement("a");
                        a.href = imgageData; //Image Base64 Goes here
                        a.download = "Image.png"; //File name Here
                        a.click(); //Downloaded file
                    }
                });
            });


        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for reply yes it was downloaded but it was not getting any extension like png or jpg can you make fix

Comment: @user12380208 I have updated the code as you requested, now you can decide the download file name and extension. please mark as answered if this work for you